# Are all kubectl commands sent to master server for processing?

Tags: kubernetes

Do all kubectl commands go to `kube-apiserver` on master node to process? For example, if you run `kubectl get pods`, does that get sent to `kube-apiserver` and processed, and if so is there a controller on that master node listening for the requests?

Answer (score 0):

All kubectl commands goes to [kube-apiserver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/) on the control plane (master nodes). With the command kubectl get pods, the request is sent to the kube-apiserver for authentication and validation, and then retrieves information and data from the ETCD database cluster to give response to the the command/request (get).

There is an [apiserver proxy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster-services/#discovering-builtin-services) on the control plane who listens requests from kube-apiserver. It is responsible on reaching node, pod or services inside the cluster

Here is the simple flow base on your command:

```
client (kubectl) --> kube-apiserver --> etcd --> kube-apiserver --> client
```

```
kube-apiserver --> apiserver-proxy --> kubelet (node) --> pods (info)

kubelet --> apiserver-proxy --> kube-apiserver --> etcd
```

[ETCD](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/) is where the cluster data is being stored and retrieved.